# C++ empty and array index

Tags: c++

Is it possible to do something like:

```
string word = "Hello";
word[3] = null;
if(word[3] == null){/.../}
```

in C++, basically making an array element empty. For example if I wanted to remove the duplicate characters from the array I'd set them to null first and then shifted the array to the left every time I found an array index that contained null.

If this is not possible what's a good way of doing something like this in C++ ?

Comment: *Adjacent* duplicate characters?  Or any duplicates whatsoever?

Comment: Sorry for not being specific enough, but I only used string as an example. I am wondering how to do something for arrays that contain ints or other general objects. And I'm interested in any duplicates whatsoever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible, since a single element of a string is an element within a char-array and thus representable as pointer, i. e. you can retrieve the address of the element. Therefore you can set `word[3] = null`. Your `if`-construct is valid but the compiler prints a warning, this is because `NULL` is only a pointer constant. Alternatives would be: `if (!word[3])` or `if(word[3] == 0)`.

But in any case you should consider using STL [algorithms](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/) for removing duplicates.

Comment: if you don't care about the order of the elements, you can use `sort(word.begin(), word.end());` and then use `word.erase( unique(word.begin(), word.end()), word.end() );`

Comment: `a single element of a string is a pointer`  That's... wrong.  Also, the if construct _is_ valid, because NULL and chars are both integral types, and compare just fine.

Comment: So what would be right then? Regarding the NULL comparison the Compiler throws a warning.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to remove adjacent duplicate characters, you can do this:

```
std::string::iterator new_end = std::unique(word.begin(), word.end());
word.erase(new_end, word.end());
```

If you want to mark arbitrary characters for removal, you can skip the marking and just provide the appropriate predicate to `std::remove_if`:

```
new_end = std::remove_if(word.begin(), word.end(), IsDuplicate);
word.erase(new_end, word.end());
```

However, I can't think of an appropriate predicate to use here that doesn't exhibit undefined behavior.  I would just write my own algorithm:

```
template<typename IteratorT>
IteratorT RemoveDuplicates(IteratorT first, IteratorT last)
{
    typedef typename std::iterator_traits<IteratorT>::value_type
            ValueT;
    std::map<ValueT, int> counts;
    for (auto scan=first; scan!=last; ++scan)
    {
        ++counts[*scan];
        if(counts[*scan] == 1)
        {
            *first = std::move(*scan);
            ++first;
        }
    }
    return first;
}
```

Or, if you don't care about the order of the elements, you could simply sort it, then use the first solution.

Comment: That seems like a pretty elegant method. Can you explain what it does?

Comment: @user1066113: The first one calls the `unique` function on the whole range of the string.  Which removes all adjacent duplicates, shifting the non-duplicates forward.  It returns an iterator to the end of the range *after* the shifting has taken place.  This iterator is then used with the string member function `erase` to erase the elements starting at that point to the end of the string, effectively resizing it.

Comment: @user1066113: The second one does something very similar using the `remove_if` function.  Instead of just adjacent duplicates though, it can remove elements based on any condition you wish, which is provided by the third argument.  I just made up the `IsDuplicate` function.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should take a look at the algorithm in the STL.
You are not very specific about what you want to remove but maybe this helps:

```
    std::string string_with_dup("AABBCCDD");
    std::string string_without_dup;
    std::cout << string_with_dup << std::endl;
    // with copy
    std::unique_copy(string_with_dup.begin(), string_with_dup.end(), std::back_inserter(string_without_dup));
    std::cout << string_without_dup << std::endl;
    // or inplace
    string_with_dup.erase(std::unique(string_with_dup.begin(), string_with_dup.end()), string_with_dup.end());
    std::cout << string_with_dup << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove all duplicates (not only the adjacent ones, you should use the [erase-remove idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase-remove_idiom) with something like this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

struct is_repeated {
    is_repeated( map<char,int>& x ) :r(&x) {};
    map<char,int>* r;
    bool operator()( char c ) {
        (*r)[c]++;
        if( (*r)[c] > 1 )
            return true;
        return false;
    }
};

int main (int argc, char**argv)
{
    map<char,int> counter_map;
    string v = "hello hello hello hello hello hello hello";
    cout << v << endl;
    is_repeated counter(counter_map);
    v.erase( remove_if(v.begin(), v.end(), counter ), v.end() );
    cout << v << endl;
}
```

outputs (as of [this](http://ideone.com/bUpmY)):

```
hello hello hello hello hello hello hello
helo
```

Comment: Your solution makes certain assumptions about the behavior of `remove_if` that are not guaranteed, see an example where it fails: http://ideone.com/rr5YU

Comment: Wow, I had no idea that the remove_if would operate in copies of my predicate... can you tell me why? (I'm editing my response to a working solution)